# Should I make the homepage the parent page of each category on a WordPress site for SEO?

Tags: seo, wordpress, homepage, page, site-structure

I want to implement good structuring practices for my website to optimize it for search engines.

My site is WordPress based. If I have some category pages - should I make the homepage the parent page of each category or is that a given?

Comment: Wordpress handles that automatically

Answer (score 5):

A *parent page* is a top-level page of a hierarchy - they have nested *child pages*.

If you are using your site’s default menu, parent pages will usually show in the menu with child pages as a drop down.

*Child* pages should be **more specific** than *parent* pages are. This is common with service pages:

`example.com/services/website-design/`

The  problem with this is that you risk your URLs becoming very lengthy. *See my rules of thumb below about 3s*

For example:

`example.com/services/seo/technical-seo/link-architecture/`

Including services there is a bit verbose. It increases the length for no reason.

---

*Categories* by contrast are applied to *posts* - they work the same way but are used to structure a blog, not the main pages of a site.

`example.com/category/postname` is very a typical URL structure for a blog. I consider it optimal because it removes `/blog/` from the URL, keeping post URLs concise.

You can also shed the category base:

`example.com/postname`

^ that will still show up on the category page as well.

https://wordpress.org/support/article/using-permalinks/

In this sense your home page *I suppose is sort of like* a parent page because `/category/` comes right after `/` but it is not *technically*. My original answer assumed you were alluding to that idea.

---

For SEO purposes, your URL structure is very much up to you. The answer to your question really depends on the style of site:

I could see it making sense if your website is like a documentation/wiki style structure with a **sidebar navigation** or a resume/personal profile.

```
Big Cats <- Homepage (parent)
|
-> Tigers //Child
|
-> Lions //Child
|
-> Panthers //Child
```

Otherwise, if your sites has a top "bar" navigation the homepage should probably not be the parent because then it would be in the navigation like this:

```
Home | Nav Item | Nav Item
|
-> Thing 1
-> Thing 2
```

---

Some general rules of thumb:

- There is benefit to having keywords in your URLs, but don't over-do it.
- Keep your URLs as short concise as possible. I don't recommend going past `example.com/one/two/three/` if possible.
- Stay away from query strings.
- Try to make sure all of your pages are within "3 clicks" from your homepage - meaning that you can get to any page with 3 clicks of your mouse.

Some other advice that might be helpful now or in the near future:

- Declare `noindex` on pages that provide little value to users
- Use redirects *sparingly* - Once you start things just get messier and messier.
- [Internal link architecture](https://moz.com/learn/seo/internal-link) is the most important concept to learn for on-page optimization. I would read up a bit on [how PageRank works](https://ahrefs.com/blog/google-pagerank/). While it might not be *as* prevalent of a rankings factor anymore...it's still PageRank.

Comment: This only partly answers the question.  Should they be using the "parent page" feature in WordPress?  https://wordpress.com/support/pages/page-options/

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Revised. Although I think this was a bit outside the scope of the original question and also adds subjectivity. My original understanding was that they were clarifying if they had to make the home page a parent of a category to achieve `example.com/category/`. I also don't know if that is even possible.